# Building queries with a cross database join using SQLalchemy ORM and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, cross-database

I have two SQLite databases containing tables I need to join using SQLalchemy. For reasons I can not combine all the tables into one SQLite database. I am using SQLalchemy ORM. I have not been able to find any solution online that meets my specific case.

My question is in principle the same as [SQLAlchemy error query join across database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749173/sqlalchemy-error-query-join-across-database), but the original poster's problem was solved using a different solution that does not match my use case.

My question to the wise people at Stackoverflow:

I want to emulate the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.gene_symbol, o.orthofinder_id FROM eukarya.genes AS g JOIN annotations.orthofinder AS o ON g.gene_id=o.gene_id;
```

This query works fine using SQliteStudio having attached both database files.

The code I am currently using to describe the metadata:

```
eukarya_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///eukarya_db.sqlite3')
annotations_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///eukarya_annotations_db.sqlite3')

meta = MetaData()  # This allows me to define cross database foreign keys

Eukarya = declarative_base(bind=eukarya_engine, metadata=meta)
Annotations = declarative_base(bind=annotations_engine, metadata=meta)
# I did the above in the hopes that by binding the engines this way,
# would percolate through the schema, and sqlalchemy would be able
# figure out which engine to use for each table.

class Genes(Eukarya):
  """SQLalchemy object representing the Genes table in the Eukarya database."""
  __tablename__ = 'genes'
  gene_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
  gene_symbol = Column(String(16), index=True)
  taxonomy_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Species.taxonomy_id), index=True)
  original_gene_id = Column(String)

class Orthofinder(Annotations):
  """SQLalchemy object representing the Orthofinder table in the Annotations database."""
  __tablename__ = 'orthofinder'
  id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  gene_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Genes.gene_id), index=True)
  orthofinder_id = Column(String(10), index=True)

Session = sessionmaker()
session = Session(bind=eukarya_engine)

print(session.query(Genes.gene_symbol,Orthofinder.orthofinder_id).
      join(Orthofinder).all().statement)
```

The last print statement returns:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: orthofinder [SQL: 'SELECT genes.gene_symbol AS genes_gene_symbol, orthofinder.orthofinder_id AS orthofinder_orthofinder_id \nFROM genes JOIN orthofinder ON genes.gene_id = orthofinder.gene_id']
```

I believe my troubles are over if I would somehow be able to bind both database engines to one session. But how?
For two databases attached to the same engine (e.g. two databases in a MySQL database) I could add `__table_args__ = {'schema': 'annotations'}` (as per [Cross database join in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433592/cross-database-join-in-sqlalchemy)), but I am unable to figure this one out in the case of SQLite.

I would prefer a solution that would allow users of my code to construct queries without having to know in which database each table resides.

Please help! And many thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036751/can-sqlalchemy-work-well-with-multiple-attached-sqlite-database-files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289837/foreign-key-in-main-database-referencing-attached-database

Comment: Thanks Illja! I've figured it out. Weird that your first link did not end up in my search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to my own question (thanks to Ilja for finding the solution):

I can define the engine like this:

```
engine  = create_engine('sqlite://',echo=True)  # generate in mem database to attach mutitple sqlite databases to.
engine.execute("attach database 'eukarya_db.sqlite3' as eukarya;")
engine.execute("attach database 'eukarya_annotations_db.sqlite3' as annotations;")
```

And then add

```
__table_args__ = {'schema': 'eukarya'}
```

or

```
__table_args__ = {'schema': 'annotations'}
```

To my table classes.

Works like a charm!